# iOS - printing memory address using PRIx64 in plCrashReporter

Tags: c, ios, ios4, macros, crash-reports

I'm trying to include plCrashReporter in my iPhone app using the code found here:

http://plcrashreporter.googlecode.com/svn/tags/plcrashreporter-1.0/Documentation/API/example_usage_iphone.html

My one issue occurs on this line:

```
 NSLog(@"Crashed with signal %@ (code %@, address=0x%" PRIx64 ")", report.signalInfo.name,
       report.signalInfo.code, report.signalInfo.address);
```

with the error:

```
error: expected `)' before 'PRIx64'
```

I tried searching around but can't find anything on this. Thoughts? report.signalInfo.address is an 64-bit unsigned int so why don't they just use %u?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PRIx64 is a macro for "X".

Answer (score 0):

@mark is right, but this change is rather intrusive, especially if you expect your code to be reused in other applications. Instead, you should make sure you have defined the following macro (it can be done on the compile line, without modifying your source code):

```
__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
```

For example, your compile line should be something like:

```
gcc -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS foo.c -o foo
```